# Jetpack compose firebase auth, why is ui updating only after reloging?

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack-compose

In my application I'm using FirebaseAuth as the logging system. In *HomeScreen* I'm displaying currently reading books based on User's firestore database. The user can update this list by adding the book to firestore database in *DetailsScreen*. The problem is that even though the database is being updated, it is being shown on the UI only if the user sign out and then log in again, it is not being shown while the user is logged in. How can i fix this? I'm providing necessarry code down below. I know, that's a lot but I simply can't find the issue.

*HomeScreen*

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
navController: NavController,
viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
commonViewModel: CommonViewModel
) {
val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
val context = LocalContext.current

val userBooks = viewModel.booksFromFB.value.filter {
    it.userId == currentUser?.uid.toString()
}
Log.d("Test", "${userBooks}")

if (viewModel.isLoading.value) {
    CircularProgressIndicator()
} else {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(gradient(colors = listOf(AppColors.mBackground, AppColors.mBackgroundSec)))
    ) {
        Log.d("Test", currentUser?.uid.toString())
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
        ) {

            Header(nick = currentUser?.email?.split('@')?.first().toString()) {
                navController.navigate(Screen.Profile.route)
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

            CurrentlyReadingSection(
                context = context,
                navController = navController,
                userBooks = userBooks,
                commonViewModel = commonViewModel
            )
```

*CurrentlyReadingSection*

```
@Composable
fun CurrentlyReadingSection(
userBooks: List<BookFB>,
context: Context = LocalContext.current,
commonViewModel: CommonViewModel,
navController: NavController
) {
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.padding()
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        text = "Currently reading",
        color = AppColors.mTextWhite,
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

    LazyRow() {
        items(userBooks) { book ->
            BookRow(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                onItemClicked = {  }
            ) {

                val isExpanded = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(false)
                }

                val isRead = rememberSaveable {
                    mutableStateOf(false)
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(AppColors.mBackgroundSec),
                    contentAlignment = BottomCenter
                ) {

                    Row {

                        AnimatedVisibility(visible = isExpanded.value) {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                                    .clickable { isExpanded.value = !isExpanded.value },
                                contentAlignment = Center
                            ) {
                                Column(
                                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                                ) {
                                    MyButton(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
                                            .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
                                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)),
                                        text = "READ",
                                        fontSize = 12,
                                        contentPadding = 8
                                    ) {
                                        isRead.value = !isRead.value
                                        isExpanded.value = !isExpanded.value
                                    }
                                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

                                    MyButton(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
                                            .fillMaxHeight(0.24f)
                                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)),
                                        text = "RATE",
                                        fontSize = 12,
                                        contentPadding = 8
                                    ) {
                                        commonViewModel.currentBook.value = book
                                        navController.navigate(Screen.Rate.route)
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        AsyncImage(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
                                .clickable { isExpanded.value = !isExpanded.value },
                            model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                                .data(
                                    if (isValid(book.image))
                                        book.image
                                    else
                                        com.example.read.R.drawable.imagenotfound
                                )
                                .crossfade(true)
                                .build(),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                            contentDescription = "Book image"
                        )
                    }

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .fillMaxHeight(0.1f)
                            .background(if (isRead.value) AppColors.mGreen else AppColors.mRed)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

*BookRow - for CurrentlyReadingSection*

```
@Composable
fun BookRow(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
book: BookFB = BookFB(),
category: MyCategory = MyCategory("", ""),
shapeDp: Int = 12,
heightSize: Int = 170,
widthSize: Int = 120,
isForYou: Boolean = false,
isYourCollection: Boolean = false,
onItemClicked: () -> Unit = {},
content: @Composable() () -> Unit,
) {

Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = if (isYourCollection) Modifier.widthIn(max = widthSize.dp) else Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Surface(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(shapeDp.dp),
        elevation = 4.dp,
        modifier = modifier.border(2.dp, color = Color.Black, shape = RoundedCornerShape(shapeDp.dp))
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    onItemClicked()
                }
                .height(heightSize.dp)
                .width(widthSize.dp)
                .background(AppColors.mBackgroundSec))
        {
            content()
        }
```

*Adding and getting books from firestore database in repository*

```
class FirebaseRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val queryBook: CollectionReference
): FirebaseRepository {
override suspend fun addToFirebase(book: BookFB) {

    if (book.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
        queryBook.add(book)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentRef ->

                val documentId = documentRef.id
                queryBook.document(documentId)
                    .update(hashMapOf("id" to documentId) as Map<String, Any>)

                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.w("Error", "AddToFirebase: Failed updating doc", it)
                    }
            }
    }
}

override suspend fun getBooksFromFB(): Resource<List<BookFB>> {
    return try {
        Resource.Loading(true)

        val response = queryBook.get().await().documents.map { documentSnapshot ->
            documentSnapshot.toObject(BookFB::class.java)!!
        }
        if (response.isNotEmpty())
            Resource.Loading(false)
        Resource.Success(response)
    } catch (exception: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
        Resource.Error(exception.message.toString())
    }
}
```

}

*Getting the books in ViewModel*

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: FirebaseRepository
): ViewModel() {

private val _booksFromFB = mutableStateOf(listOf<BookFB>())
val booksFromFB = _booksFromFB
private val _isLoading = mutableStateOf(true)
val isLoading = _isLoading

init {
    getBooksFromFB()
}

fun getBooksFromFB() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _isLoading.value = true
        _booksFromFB.value = repository.getBooksFromFB().data!!

        if (_booksFromFB.value.isNotEmpty())
            _isLoading.value = false
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).